# UserForm with multiple tabs

Tags: java, swing, tabs

I am trying to figure out how to create a user form that has multiple tabs like the image below.

http://img25.imageshack.us/i/multipletabs.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JTabbedPane`.

The Swing tutorial for Tabbed Panes is very handy:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html